# How to make the ASP web pages designed in IE6 compatible to IE8?

Tags: asp.net, css

My web applications are designed in IE6 compatibility mode. Now I need to migrate to IE8, but most of my web pages are not in good allignment in IE8 browser. First I tried the compatibility view in IE8(the button near the address bar), but of no use. Then as per somebodies suggestion I have added the meta tag '' in the  section of every html pages, but still it is not working. I am using Windows XP professional OS version 2002 with service pack3 and IIS version 5.1. I am not sure I can migrate to IE8 with this system configuration. Moreover I am a beginner in this session. Could somebody please explain how can I acheive this?

Thanks in advance,
Lakshmi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good place to start would be to open up the pages in a tool like visual studio and look at the list of violations listed.  Go down the list and start fixing things that are deprecated or wrong.   Notepad++ has an "HTML Tidy" feature that will reformat and correct some common mistakes.  However, many of the problems that you are going to encounter are not trivial - as in the entire paradigm followed is probably wrong.   Converting a site is, unfortunately not the type of thing that we can do by running the pages through a wizard.   I would start by creating a new MasterPage (or global template for whatever framework) that uses CSS for formatting and layout.   Then you can migrate blocks of text into the new "skeleton".   Some of the CSS template sites offer really nice free templates.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Good shout on the standards violations - using a W3C validator will help in this respect as well - http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: Thanks Trey...So you mean to say that I have to create a Master page and put all the standard formatting and layout corresponding to IE8?

Comment: It's the content that the browser sees that matters.   The browser is completely agnostic about which particular webserver sent it the content.  So, yes, IE8 will work for a site served by iis5.   That said, your site would be much easier to secure, configure, etc. on IIS 7.5; so upgrade the web server if you can.

Comment: Yes, design a good master page that looks correct under all of the target browsers and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

If this helps you, the new IE 9 has developer tools (F12) which allow you to use either the IE7, IE8 or IE9 rendering engines to view any page.

As a best practise, when making any content for the web you should be checking compatibility on at least the 3 main browsers (IE, Chrome, Firefox), and probably some of the others (Safari). There are Visual Studio add-ins that can help with this kind of thing, by choosing which browser(s) are used for debug mode.

Some of the developer tool suites also allow you to edit content in the browser which can be a big time saver. This lets you tweak CSS and HTML and see the results in real-time, you then just have to apply your changes to the original code. Chrome, FireFox and IE (newer versions) all have tools for this kind of thing, and/or free plug-ins.

You will find in IE8 that the behaviour is better than IE7 and IE6 but still far from perfect, but should notice that the behaviour across Firefox, Chrome, Safari etc is fairly consistent.